# Order of execution java statements

Tags: java, jvm

Since order of execution is not guaranteed. In below program order of execution for main method can be like below ?

```
 t2.start();
 t2.join(); 
 t1.start();
 t1.join();
```

Program is:

```
public class Puzzle {
  static boolean answerReady = false;
  static int answer = 0;
  static Thread t1 =
      new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          answer = 42;
          answerReady = true;
        }
      };
  static Thread t2 =
      new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          while (!answerReady) Thread.sleep(100);
          System.out.println("The meaning of life is: " + answer);
        }
      };

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
  }
}
```

Edit: want to add few things after seeing comments

1. answerReady may never become true. Agree.
2. what are special conditions when order of execution can be changed ?
3. why main method is correctly synchronized here ?

Comment: Hint: you want us to help, but you are unwilling to spend 1 more minute to edit your source for proper formatting?!

Comment: Order of execution is not guaranteed ***in some very specific situations***. In your case you are guaranteed that those four statements will be executed in the correct order.

Comment: I will correct it , just could not do with mobile

Comment: @Vilpin I already fixed it for you, twice. Please don't revert it again.

Comment: There is no guarantee that code will ever finish executing; and if it does, there's no guarantee that it will print 42.

Comment: @Jägermeister i can definitely spend, i posted question using app and couldn't format it my bad.

Comment: @assylias what are those specific situations when order of execution is not guaranteed. This is exactly I need.

Comment: @Vipin The answer to that question could fill an entire book! In substance, your main method is correctly synchronized and will therefore execute in an order that is consistent with the program order. The code within the two threads however is not correctly synchronized, hence Andy Turner's comment. If you want to know the details, you may want to read https://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601

Comment: Or for a lighter intro: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html - or for the gory details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html

Comment: @assylias as you said "your main method is correctly synchronized" , I am not able to understand this because I have not done anything to make it correctly synchronized. Your comments have depth of knowledge (at least for me) if you can not put together all in answer at the end i will try to write a answer as community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Language Specification dictates what conforming JVMs may do or not. See

> #### [§17.4.5. Happens-before Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)
>
> Two actions can be ordered by a *happens-before* relationship. If one action *happens-before* another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.
>
> If we have two actions *x* and *y*, we write *hb(x, y)* to indicate that *x happens-before y*.
>
> - If *x* and *y* are actions of the same thread and *x* comes before *y* in program order, then *hb(x, y)*.
> - …

Since your invocations of `start()` and `join()` are actions of the same thread, they are ordered in respect to the program order.

I think, it should be obvious that if that simple guaranty didn’t exist, even single threaded programming was impossible.

This does not imply the absence of reordering in the code. It only implies that such optimizations must happen in a way that retains the observable behavior of these actions when executing this code.

The point here is, that while the main thread will consistently do what you told it to do, other threads not having a *happens-before* relationship to either of these actions, might not see the actions in the same way. In your case, with the three threads shown, there are several relationships:

<sub>continuation of §17.4.5</sub>

> - …
> - If *hb(x, y)* and *hb(y, z)*, then *hb(x, z)*.
>
> …
>
> - A call to `start()` on a thread *happens-before* any actions in the started thread.
> - All actions in a thread *happen-before* any other thread successfully returns from a `join()` on that thread.

From this you can derive that all three threads of your code agree on what the main thread is doing in most parts.

Of course, this doesn’t change the fact that the two spawned threads are improperly (not at all) synchronized and `t2` may print the value `0` instead of `42` or never terminate at all.

Comment: in main method  t2.start() will be followed by t2.join() similarly t1.start() then t1.join(). But both t1 and t2 are independent so it is possible to order like I gave in question. This is my question here.

Comment: Your premise “*But both t1 and t2 are independent*” makes no sense here. These four method invocations represent observable *actions* and as shown in my answer, have a strict ordering. The fact that these actions are related to threads is completely irrelevant. It’s like you had written `System.out.println("first"); System.out.println("second");` and asked whether that could be reordered to `System.out.println("second"); System.out.println("first");`. *Of course not*.

Comment: why "of course not", that is my question. Probably in sysout it is clear because it is going to change output of program but in case of threads t1 and t2 main main doesn't know what these are doing internally.

Comment: I already gave you *the specification*. If the specification says, that these actions happen in order, they do. The point is *you* are trying to invent some kind of new rule about what the main thread knows about t1 and t2, but such a rule doesn’t exist. Starting threads or waiting for threads are observable actions, hence, the observable behavior has to follow the cited rules. What t1 or t2 do is irrelevant for what the main thread does.

Comment: I have asked this question because I do not know and my understanding about this concept is wrong. I have just explained what i think in this case should be so that you can clearly understand my view and point me to right direction. Not trying to invent rules here :) , coming back to discussion, if i follow specification snippet you provided then reordering is not possible in single thread execution in that case how JIT does reordering in single threaded env ?

Comment: One more line from same jls reference you provided is : "It should be noted that the presence of a happens-before relationship between two actions does not necessarily imply that they have to take place in that order in an implementation. If the reordering produces results consistent with a legal execution, it is not illegal." since t1 and t2 are 2 independent threads it should be legal to reorder them.

Comment: You are again confusing the threads with the four method invocations made by the main method. Again, there is *nothing* regarding the two threads t1 and t2 that can influence what the main thread will do. The main thread performs four method invocations, each with an observable side effect, nothing more, nothing less. There are no other threads involved, the `main` method is executed by a single thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116594/discussion-between-vipin-and-holger).

Answer (score 2):

No. the order of execution on the main thread is as you've declared it in `main`:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

The only thing that's not guaraneed is the content of the threads `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: JIT can reorder statements in order to optimize, then why cant it reorder here ?

Comment: See @assylias comment on your question.